# How to Remove Background Color (PowerShell)

Tags: powershell, colors

I was playing around with PowerShell today and added a background color to all text ...now I want it gone!

Anyone know how to do that, as a side note I was trying to change the color of the whole blank area that fills the application (formerly known as the background ...good job Microsoft) so if you know how to do that please do share.

Answer (score 2):

Click on the icon in the upper left, select Properties, go to the Colors tab.